# Keyboard event with ionic form

Tags: javascript, html, events, ionic-framework

I have an input field in my ionic form:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchKey">
<button class="button button-clear" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
```

And I wanna add an event that calls the function "search()" when I press enter button of my keyboard.

Is there any suggestion ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this directive [ng-enter](https://gist.github.com/EpokK/5884263), like this

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-enter="search()" ng-model="searchKey">
```