# Ionic & Cordova, how to listen for the done button or any button event

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard-events, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an input field in my html. I'm trying to figure out how to listen for the native keyboards done button. I'm new to using web languages and the hybrid stack so finding documentation has been a bit of a challenge. Any help would be amazing

Here's my html

```
<div class="bar bar-header nav-search-width">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper textbox-search">
        <i class="icon ion-searchicon placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input id="searchEventsBar" type="search" placeholder="Search All Events" ng-model="searchQuery">
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer to my question in another stackoverflow post after digging for about an two hours or so. 
[Listening for keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645855/keyboard-event-with-ionic-form)

In my html I needed to add a new directive: ng-enter

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-enter="search()" ng-model="searchKey">
```

Then I created the below directive. The `13` in `if(event.which === 13)`  maps to the done button.  I should mention for anyone else who is new, make sure you replace `app` with your module.

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {
                        scope.$apply(function(){
                                scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                        });

                        event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
});
```